# Java (TomCat) Servlet login security. HTTP vs HTTPS (development and production)

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, ssl, https

I work with proof of concept web application, and have to create login/password authentication. For now security is not a matter, but further in production it will be important. My first question: Should I already configure TomCAT with SSL certificate to work via HTTPS? Is this somehow affects servlet implementation? Can I just develop everything using http, and just switch to https on production?

I think web application should work with any HTTP or HTTPs and this depends only on servlet container (TomCAT) setup, but I am not sure. Now I work with [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/bncby/index.html) manual  with some changes, especially in sense of TomCAT 8 and annotations use.

Also, please note some parts of my application will use websocket protocol.

Thanks.

Comment: "Tune up" an SSL certificate?  This makes no sense.

Comment: Why you think this non sense? As I understand to use HTTPS I should generate and put SSL certificate to server? Is this wrong?

Comment: @Pavlo You better say it `configuration` ;)

Comment: Thanks. I edit post. May be my first attempt was confusing.

Comment: If you have SSL enabled you will have session tracking for free, no need to use cookies or URL rewriting. This could be an interesting point to watch out in your implementation